# Git push Existing Repo to New Remote: Connection to github.com closed by remote host

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have an existing repo I want to push to new url. I tried the following.

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/new-repo.git
$ git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
$ git config --global ssh.postBuffer 1048576000
$ git push --verbose
Pushing to github.com:user/new-repo.git
Enumerating objects: 2729, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2729/2729), done.
Delta compression using up to 24 threads
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
error: pack-objects died of signal 2)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

$ git repack
Enumerating objects: 2999, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2732/2732), done.
Delta compression using up to 24 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2548/2548), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2732/2732), done.
Total 2732 (delta 1716), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0

$ git push --verbose
Pushing to github.com:user/new-repo.git
Enumerating objects: 2729, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2729/2729), done.
Delta compression using up to 24 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1115/1115), done.
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
error: remote unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To github.com:user/new-repo.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:user/new-repo.git'
```

In a separate copy of repo:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/new-repo.git
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/user/new-repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user/new-repo.git (push)

$ git push
Enumerating objects: 2729, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2729/2729), done.
Delta compression using up to 24 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2106/2106), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2729/2729), 2.50 GiB | 3.01 MiB/s, done.
Total 2729 (delta 1723), reused 706 (delta 395), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

The original repo is hosted on gitlab. Using github's import feature also fails, without a descriptive message. Gitlab shows the repo is 3.7GB and there no really large individual files.

Any debugging ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the issue persists:

- using the latest Git 2.28
- using an https URL (for testing): `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/new-repo.git`
- using a small content in the new repository (again, for testing: a first commit with only a few small files)

The last point seems pertinent:

```
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size
```

Try and make sure your first commit is not "too big" for a GitHub push to handle.

Comment: I updated to Git 2.28, with no change in results. My test repository pushes fine. I added the https results to main post. The https result is different but did not work.

Comment: @harkib Does it fail if your initial commit is made of just a few files?

Comment: How do you go about making the initial commit just a few files. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @harkib When you create your local repository, instead of doing `git add .` (which adds *everything*), just add a few files (`git add file1`, `git add file2`, ...). Then commit and push.

Comment: I have a complete repo. Everything was committed and pushed to the old repo. I locally copied the repo and changed the url. How would I go about making this initial commit to the new repo smaller?